# Solving a Quadratic Ternary Form with Large Coefficients

Tags: quadratic-forms, sums-of-squares

I encountered this expression 
$$1215696x^2+566544y^2-103776z^2=0$$
which I've understood is called a "quadratic ternary form" and have been trying to find solutions $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$

One can firstly remove a common factor of $48$ and obtain
$$25327x^2+11803y^2-2162z^2=0$$
At this point, the coefficients are already square free. I'm trying to follow Legendre's theorem on these forms (which I understand to characterize solvability) and Lagrange's method of descent (which I understand finds initial solutions).  I've had no luck so far.

I've noted too that each of the coefficients are congruent numbers. Specifically, they are of the form $4mn(m^2-n^2)$ for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Would this fact be enough to determine solvability?

Comment: it turns out that the only primes involved that allow this thing are $2,47.$ I encourage you to show how your equation is blocked by six primes, $11,19,23,29, 37,43.$ Slight changes in the argument each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible in the $23$-adic numbers. The calculation is that, if
$$ 25327 x^2 + 11803 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {23}, $$ then, in fact, both $x$ and $y$ are divisible by $23.$ Therefore $$ 25327 x^2 + 11803 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {23^2}, $$ from which we get $z \equiv 0 \pmod {23.}$ This contradicts the standard assumption that we have a solution with $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1.$

Calculations: $2162 = 2 \cdot 23 \cdot 47. \; \; \; $  $25327 = 4 + 23 \cdot 1101. \; \; \; $ $11803 = 4 + 23 \cdot 513.$ 
$$ 4 x^2 + 4 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {23}. $$
$$  x^2 +  y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {23}. $$
ASSUME that $y$ is not divisible by $23.$ Then we can do
$$  x^2   \equiv - y^2 \pmod {23}. $$
$$  \frac{x^2}{y^2}   \equiv - 1 \pmod {23}, $$
$$  \left(\frac{x}{y} \right)^2  \equiv - 1 \pmod {23}. $$
This contradicts the fact that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ which includes $q=23.$

In case of interest: by the product formula for the Hilbert Norm Residue symbol, there must be an even count of primes  which block your problem. There is no problem with the prime $2,$ but there are several others as factors.

NOTE: I like the treatment in Cassels, *Rational Quadratic Forms*. He makes it very clear that one must check each prime separately, and in earlier pages shows ways to accomplish that.

Comment: So if the form cannot be solved in some $p$-adic field, it follows that it is also not solvable over the integers?

Comment: @ChristianWoll True. On the other hand, for this problem, you just need to be confident in how to calculate $\pmod {23},$ basics of quadratic residues, and firm about the gcd of integers. That is my way of doing "infinite descent," if there were any solution in integers, not all zero, there would be a solution with $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1.$ Easy lemma, worth learning in detail